# Write extracted data to a file using jmeter

Tags: file-io, jmeter

I am using JMeter v2.5.
I need to get data from the responses of the test and extract data from it (which I am doing using regular exp extractor). How do I store this extracted data to a file?

Answer (score 38):

Just solved a similar problem. After getting the data using a regular expression extractor, add a BeanShell PostProcessor element. Use the code below to write the variables to a file:

```
name = vars.get("name");
email = vars.get("email");

log.info(email);  // if you want to log something to jmeter.log file

// Pass true if you want to append to existing file
// If you want to overwrite, then don't pass the second argument
f = new FileOutputStream("/my/file/path/result.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(name + "," + email);
f.close();
```

Comment: Also this [link](https://ansonliao.gitbooks.io/jmeter-skill/content/jmeter_how_to_save_variables_to_a_file_after_getting_the_data_using_a_regular_expression_extractor.html) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to write extracted variables to CSV results file, then just add to user.properties the variables you want:

> sample_variables=name,email

As per doc:

- https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config

They will be appended as last column of CSV results file.

Comment: This helped me. I'm using Azure Load Testing and my variable appears in the result CSV. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You may use https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FlexibleFileWriter/ with sample variables set up. 
Or with fake Dummy Sampler. 
Anyway Flexible File Writer is good for writing data into file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;

String path=FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir();

name1= vars.get("user_Name_value");
name2= vars.get("UserId_value");

f = new FileOutputStream("E://csvfile/result.csv", true); //spec-ify true if you want to overwrite file. Keep blank otherwise.
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
p.println(name1+"," +name2);
f.close();
```

this is worked for me i hope it will work for you also

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options

1. You can tally the results by adding an aggregate report listener to your thread group => add listener => aggregate report
2. You can get raw results by adding a simple data writer listener to your thread group => add listener => simple data writer

Hope this helps

Comment: Actually I need to extact the title and content of the blog in two separate variables and then write them into a certain file in suitable format.