# Parse an array from the response message using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am a beginner with Jmeter tool. 
I use JMeter to hit a URL and obtained a response message in JSON format.
I want to parse the response to extract every array element and use it to append to the tail of another URL. Can you please tell me how to do this?

```
example: { "reply": { "code": "111", "status": "SUCCESS", "customer": [ "222-a", "b-333", "44-4", "s-555", "666", "777", "88-8" ] } }
```

Comment: example: {
    "reply": {
        "code": "111",
        "status": "SUCCESS",
        "customer": [
            "222-a",
            "b-333",
            "44-4",
            "s-555",
            "666",
            "777",
            "88-8"
        ]
    }
}

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a **Regular Expression Extractor** (as child of your URL sampler) to first extract the array of values:

```
Reference name: ary
Regular Expression: \[([^\]]+)\]
Template: $1$
Match No: 1
```

then use another **Regular Expression Extractor** to extract the values:

```
Apply To JMeter variable: ary

Reference name: vals
Regular Expression: "([^"]+)"
Template: $1$
Match No: -1
```

The match no -1 creates variables `vals_1 .. vals_7`, which you can then use in a **ForEach Controller** to assign to a JMeter variable:

```
Input variable prefix: vals
Output variable name: id
[v] Add '_' before number?
```

now you can use the JMeter variable ${id} in a nested URL sampler to pass the customer id in a URL.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. Your last comment is what exactly I am trying to do "now you can use the JMeter variable ${id} in a nested URL sampler to pass the customer id in a URL." but in a different thread group. Can you please tell me how to use this variable in the following thread group. Thank you

Comment: Looping through all output of a RegExp extractor. Can you please tell me how to loop through the result of a Regex Post Processor that returns multiple values?

Comment: @Sashi, JMeter variables are local to the current thread, as far as I know you cannot pass them to other threads. However you could try to save them (in the foreach controller) to a file which is used in a CSV controller in the next thread group, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter (btw, I never tried this.)

Comment: @Sashi, the Foreach controller assigns the values to a variable (`id` in the text above) which you can expand in URL samplers that are child nodes of the foreach.