# How to write a variable into a text file in Jmeter

Tags: javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

What i'm trying to do is to extract a value using a Regular Expression. I extracted the value but Now I need to write this extracted value to a text file or to an other source so I can reuse it later. Any ideas how I can achieve this. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BSF processor and use one of scripting language to write to the file using the respective api calls in selected scripting language.

Comment: I cannot get any Java COde to run,,How can I import Java.io.*; into the script?

Comment: If you don't have to stick to java you can use beanshell. Check this out for exact answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter

Comment: Please share your finding, so that others can benefit.