# How to write Jmeter Regex into a file after extraction

Tags: jmeter

In my Jmeter test, I am able to use REGEX Extraction, After extraction I want to write the value of the REGEX variable into a file

I found a workaround as using beanshell as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15159521/4556894

Is there any clean way of doing it, May be some inbuilt features, which I am not aware of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to write variable values into JMeter .jtl results file. There is a JMeter Property called `sample_variables`

> Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
>
> Use commas to separate the names.For example:
>
> sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE

So if you run JMeter in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) as follows:

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=myVariable -n -t /path/to/your/testplan.jmx -l /path/to/testresults.jtl
```

You'll get the output like

```
timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,bytes,grpThreads,allThreads,Latency,"myVariable"

1425978657207,368,HTTP Request,200,OK,Thread Group 1-1,text,true,1591,1,1,367,YOUR_VARIABLE_VALUE
```

In above example column names are given for reference, they are not included into csv results file by default. This behavior is controllable via `jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names` property, set it to "true" to get column names printed along with results data.

You can also set `sample_variables` property value in *user.properties* file which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation or uncomment it in *jmeter.properties* file (same location)

For more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and/or overriding them refer to [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)