# Get the downloaded file name from sampler response in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have created a script in JMeter to download a file and now I have to get the name of the downloaded file [filename] from sampler response to store it in a csv file,
I have tried to configure the sampler response but it didn't help me out.
please see the following

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 1235270
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Expires: Mon, 20 Apr 2015 12:10:35 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
content-disposition: attachment; **filename="10098_testcase_package.pct**"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to get "filename" bit from response header you can use [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) post processor for it

1. Add Regular Expression Extractor **as a child** of the request which returns the header
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Field to check: `Response Headers`. It matters as by default the Extractor looks up in the response body and you need the header.
   - Reference Name: any variable name, i.e `filename`
   - Regular Expression: `filename="(.+?)"`
   - Template: `$1$`

   Other fileds may be left blank

[image: Regular Expression Extractor]

You can refer extracted value as `${filename}` where required.

For more information on correlation in JMeter check out [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) guide.

Comment: It works, thanks.
But i have a query, how to provide the reference name in a csv

Comment: @PrateekBhati To write values to files, you can use a beanshell postprocessor. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter)