# How to write a JSON extracted value to a csv file in jmeter for a specific variable

Tags: json, csv, jmeter

I have a csv file that looks like this:

```
varCust_id,varCust_name,varCity,varStateProv,varCountry,varUserId,varUsername
```

When I run the HTTP Post Request to create a new customer, I get a JSON response.  I am extracting the cust_id and cust_name using the json extractor.  How can I enter this new value into the csv for the correct variable?  For example, after creating the customer, the csv would look like this:

```
varCust_id,varCust_name,varCity,varStateProv,varCountry,varUserId,varUsername
1234,My Customer Name
```

Or once I create a user, the file might look like this:

```
varCust_id,varCust_name,varCity,varStateProv,varCountry,varUserId,varUsername
1234,My Customer Name,,,,9876,myusername
```

In my searching through the net, I have found ways and I'm able to append these extracted variables to a new line but in my case, I need to replace the value in the correct location so it is associated to the correct variable I have set up in the csv file.

Answer (score 0):

Well, never tried this. But what you can do is create all these variables and set them to `Null / 0`.

Once done, update these during your execution. At the end, you can concatenate these with any delimiter (say ; or Tab) and just push in CSV as a single string.
Once you got data in CSV, you can easily split in Ms excel.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking to do can be done via a BeanShell PostProcessor and is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the reply.  I ended up using User Defined Variables for some things and BeanShell PreProcessors for other bits vs. using the CSV.