# count and write the number of extracted values in regex

Tags: jmeter

I have a json with the below section. I want to write the number of providers and write it on the result file. For example there are 10 providers in this. So my requirement is to write the number 10 in the file. How can i  do it?

```
 "providers":
    [
        {
            "MM_logofile":"agd.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"AGD",
            "name":"Agoda.com",
            "logo":"AGD.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"bks.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"BKS",
            "name":"Booking.com",
            "logo":"BKS.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"pln.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"PLN",
            "name":"Priceline.com",
            "logo":"PLN.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"ian.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"IAN",
            "name":"Hotels.com",
            "logo":"IAN-Other.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"gar.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"GAR",
            "name":"getaroom.com",
            "logo":"GAR.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"htv.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"HTV",
            "name":"HotelTravel.com",
            "logo":"HTV.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"exp.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"EXP",
            "name":"Expedia.dk",
            "logo":"EXP-DK.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":null,
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":true,
            "code":"BOO",
            "name":"Book with hotel",
            "logo":"",
            "isOfficial":true
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"hcl.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"HCL",
            "name":"HotelsClick.com",
            "logo":"HCL.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        },
        {
            "MM_logofile":"vnn.svg",
            "MM_isOfficialWithoutLogo":false,
            "code":"VNN",
            "name":"Venere.com",
            "logo":"VNN.png",
            "isOfficial":false
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [JSONPATH Extractor](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/?utm_source=jmeter&utm_medium=helplink&utm_campaign=JSONPathExtractor) plugin (use Jmeter-plugin manager to add the plugin) and add it as a child to the sampler in which you get the JSON response.

Use the expression as follows:

```
$.providers[*]
```

and reference name as `providers` as shown in the below image

[image]

Once you captured the values into reference variables, later you can use the reference name as follows to get the count of matched results (i.e., number of providers) as follows:

```
${providers_matchNr}
```

[image]

**To save the provider's count to a file:**

Add BeanShell Post processor and add the following code:

```
    count = vars.get("providers_matchNr");

log.info(count);  // if you want to log something to jmeter.log file

// Pass true if you want to append to existing file
// If you want to overwrite, then don't pass the second argument
f = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\USER_HP_2013_03\\Desktop\\New folder\\result.csv", true);
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p); 
print(count);
f.close();
```

Reference image:

[image]

Reference:

1. [Write extracted data to a file using jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter)

Comment: thanks for the reply Naveen. is it possible to write the number of providers in a file?

Comment: you can. add BeanShell postprocessor, create a file and write to it. (beanShell script is like a scripting language written in Java) once file is created, use one of the File writing options. you can retrieve the value using var.get("providers_matchNr") as mentioned before in benshell sampler.

Comment: updated the answer. try out. remember to change the path of file as per your machine

Comment: I used the below script to write on the file, but doesn't seem to be working. can you help?


import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;
tempVar = var.get("providers_matchNr");


// Open File(s)

f = new FileOutputStream(FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir()+"\\hotelsupplier.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
this.interpreter.setOut(p);
// Write data to file 
p.println(tempVar);

// Close File(s)
p.close();f.close();

Comment: can you add it in your question as code? I am not able to format it.

Comment: can you try first hardcoding the path as shown in the answer instead of getting the path from FileServer? by the way what is the error you are getting in the logs?

Comment: I tried hardcoding the path as well. this is the error 'jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer; //int tempVar = vars.get("provider . . . '' : Object constructor '

Comment: what is the code you tried? with FileServer or without FileServer? you can share the code that you are trying by EDITING the question (add the code at the end of the question in EDIT section). Use "Edit" option available at bottom of the question (in middle of "share" and "flag" options).

Comment: got it to work now. it was a silly mistake. i did not parse the integer.

Comment: I have another question. Let me post it as a new question. Hope you can help that too. that one is a bit complicated :)

Comment: I will :) but request to accept the answer and upvote it so others can also get help from it. I am saying it as I see you as a new user in SO.

Comment: I will. But how do I request to accept the answer? I tried posting the complete JSON response but I'm not able to because it is too long. is there a way around?

Comment: top left to my answer, you can see a tick mark, to accept the answer. and uparrow to upvote, downarrow to downvote.

Comment: try to make it short and only share the json where the focus is required.

Comment: Done!  apparently my vote will not be displayed coz im new. Yes, will edit and post the response. Thanks a lot!

Comment: another question on this - i have extracted the hotel name as well. Is it possible to write the hotel name in one column and providers_matchNr in another column in an excel file?

Comment: I am not sure about excel, but you can definitely try with csv file use "," or "\t" b/w the values while writing and at the end write "\n' for new line so that new record will be inserted into newline each time.

Comment: yeah i tried with "," in csv. but thought it would be easier to write in separate columns. Thanks for the help! any ideas on the other question?

Comment: Also when I write on the file, it is starting from the second row. why is that so? and how can i write from the first row?

Comment: not sure why it started from the second line, it is not expected. may be you written \n in the beginning itself or the first row does not have any content. work in progress for other question

Comment: I haven't written \n in the code, i don't think it is a blank content as well. because it is not writing string as well in the first line.

Comment: disable Debug sampler in case present. that may be causing the first empty line. added answer to other question

Comment: I have a follow up question. In this we are extracting providers and getting the total providers in providers_matchNr. I tried to include it in summary report by updating the property file. But I would like the name to be "Total providers" instead of "providers_matchNr". Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Yes. Use beanshell which is already there in the answer. There, add one more line as follows: vars.put("Total Providers", count);  so, toh can refer the value using "Total Providers".