# Jmeter - store variable data for an hour

Tags: jmeter

Is there a way to access Jmeter variable data even after tests are run?

This is what i am looking for:

1. Run a test, store the data in a variable (test finishes in 2 mins)
2. Idle for 15 mins
3. Run another test

i want the variable in step 3, Without running step1 again.

Comment: you can write and read from file. Is it an option for you?

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward choice is saving the variable(s) you need into JMeter's .jtl results file using [Sample Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property. In order to "tell" JMeter to save certain variable value you need to add the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
sample_variables=your_variable_name
```

Alternatively you can pass this property value using [-J command-line argument](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)

```
jmeter -Jsample_variables=your_variable_name -n -t ....
```

Once done you should see an extra column in the .jtl results file holding your variable values. You should be able to access these values using i.e. [CSV Data Set Config](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733689-Using-CSV-DATA-SET-CONFIG).

See [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are per test. You need to use a resource as file.

Use propert file to save and load variable as follows:

Start jmeter with property file as `-q my.properties`

On your test check if property exists if exists skip step 1

If not - do step 1 and then  add the variable to property file line as `propName=propValue`
See [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter)